# cannot get access token in facebook api 5

Tags: laravel, facebook-php-sdk

I cannot get a facebook access token from the following code. I am using  laravel4, and with this code I can successfully log in from facebook.

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook(['app_id'=> Config::get('facebook.app_id'),
      'app_secret' => Config::get('facebook.app_secret'),
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
      ]);
 $this->helper  = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
```

`$accessToken` returns `null`, any idea why?

Comment: Should you be using `$this->helper`?

Comment: sorry last line is  I added to explain  I use $this->helper in my website

Comment: even I use 
dd($fb->getRedirectLoginHelper()->getAccessToken());  still return null

Answer (score -1):

this is not teh way to get the token you should return redirect to the 
$fb->getRedirectLoginHelper()->getRedirecturl() and on returning after authentication should use the auth code to generate the token. If you donot have much idea about how oauth login flow works i would recommend you to use laravel/socialite package.

Its very easy to handle all social logins. https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#social-authentication

Comment: thanks for your comment  unfortunately I use laravel4  this version can not support socialite I try hybridauth.github.io/hybridauth  but I can not logout user from facebook , so I decide to use orignal sdk. Btw way how to logout user from facebook